# Issue in converting received ajax data

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajax is used to retrieve data from server.

Data is displayed successfully on alert as

```
data: {"status": "Active","broadcastmsg": "msg"}
```

But in html i.e. `<p id="demo"></p>` it is displayed as **undefined**.

Looks like a minor issue , though I have been trying to solve this since last 24 hours and nothing seems to be working. Please suggest what's going wrong.

> Client.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<script>
    function myFunction(val) {

            $.post("test.php",
            {
              d_id: 1,
              date: val
            },
            function(hstatus){
                alert(hstatus);
                myJSON = JSON.stringify(hstatus);
                localStorage.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);

                //Retrieving data:
                text = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");
                obj = JSON.parse(text);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.status;
            });
        }

    </script>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <div id="future_date" style="display:block;" class="col-xs-12">             
            <input type="date" name="txt" value="" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
        </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

> EDIT

if we pass `hstatus = {"status": "Active","broadcastmsg": "msg"}` manually it's showing result.

Thus issue is in converting from

`data: {"status": "Active","broadcastmsg": "msg"}`

to

`{"status": "Active","broadcastmsg": "msg"}`

Comment: Maybe your `.status` is inside `.data` in the response? Try with `obj.data.status`. If that doesn't work, try debugging using `console.log()` and `console.dir()`, these will be more useful than `alert()`.

Comment: I think the debugger is your friend here. Have you tried stepping through it to see exactly what you are receiving and what is coming from local storage? My best guess at the moment is that `hstatus` is coming in as a string, not an object.

Comment: @yuriy636 nope, undefined is not displayed at all that way

Comment: @JackA. if I pass -> hstatus = {"status": "Holiday","broadcastmsg": "6"} it's showing result. So the thing is it's unable to read -> data: {"status": "Active","broadcastmsg": "msg"}

Comment: @JackA. question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

If you have the "data: " part in front of the JSON data, you have to trim:

```
myJSON = hstatus.substring(6);
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

**Option A:**
You should include one more (`dataType`) parameter in the `$.post` call, so the jQuery knows the content type, otherwise you will get the response as plain text.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post("test.php", {
     d_id: 1,
     date: val
}, function() { /*...*/ }, 
"json");
```

You should also check your test.php and ensure that you are sending the `Content-Type: application/json` http header (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

**Option B:** (not recommended)
Just remove the `JSON.stringify()` part from the callback function:

```
function(hstatus){
    localStorage.setItem("testJSON", hstatus);
    //Retrieving data:
    text = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");
    obj = JSON.parse(text);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.status;
});
```

Just a tip:

Use the `console.log()` command for debug variable values so you can see the exact, typed value in your browser console (press F12 in most browser). 
The `alert()` function automatically converts everything into strings so it usually show misleading results.

Comment: when used content-type as application/json no output was received. Also checked through console.log(), output is same i.e. data: {"status": "Active","broadcastmsg": "6"}

Comment: is it safe? as we are substracting string

Comment: @Observer: My original answer was based on you are sending a valid JSON response from test.php. But you are sending plain text which contains some JSON data. You can try to find the first occurence of the "{" character and split the string.

Comment: Issue was in php file, it contained 'data' which I assumed was part of sending protocal

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is the format of string which is coming from server.

if your alert is giving this output:
data: {"status": "Active","broadcastmsg": "msg"}
Then JSON.parse won't be able to parse it. Since it's not an object or any type. This will give a syntax error.

Following is the right format of string which you should send from server then everything JSON.parse will work fine.
{"data": {"status": "Active","broadcastmsg": "msg"}}

So solution for this which I can guess is:
hstatus parameter of success callback is of [plainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)
So try following:

```
myJSON = JSON.stringify(hstatus.data);
```

Let me know in case it doesnt work, will dig more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.data.status;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your `status` property via `obj.data.status` instead of `obj.status`

```
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.data.status;
```